# Mock 'document' with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, document

I'm using `document.hidden` and I need to mock it as `true` or `false` in my unit tests.
So I made this:

```
documentMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['hidden']);

module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('document', documentMock);
});
```

But `hidden` is always returning false.

Answer (score 1):

`$provide` is used to register things with Angular's injector. Unless your code under test is injecting something called `document` (which is not good, since that will conflict with the global document object), you should be doing a `$provide.value('$document', documentMock)` instead. `$document` [is an Angular injectable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) and a wrapper around the global document object, so the code under test should also be referencing `$document`.